# What will be the complexity of the following code?

Tags: java, c, data-structures, complexity-theory

I have written a code as bellow, but i have confusion whether complexity of this algorithm is O(n) or O(n<sup>2</sup>). Can any body please confirm me?

```
  for(int i=0, j=i+1;i<array.length;j++)
    {

        if(j==array.length)
        {
            if(array[i]==3)
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            i++;                
            j=i;
            continue;
        }

        int k=array[i]+array[j];
        if(k==3)
        {
            System.out.println("{"+array[i]+","+array[j]+"}");
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Udy `j` **is** declared in the first loop

Comment: It is compiling file. Why should'nt it complie?

Comment: It might be O(n) but it's definitely not o(n).

Answer (score 4):

The only important part is this:

```
for (int i=0, j=i+1; i < array.length; j++)
{
    if (j == array.length)
    {
        ...
        i++;                
        j=i;
        continue;
    }
 ...
 }
```

The loop is running for `j = i+1` to `j == array.length`; then `i` is incremented and the loop on `j` repeats.

Therefore this is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

Comment: the "small ommission of n^2" is the first thing one will read and the only important part of the answer.

Comment: That's what comments are for:  politely pointing out an ommission in the answer. In fact, you may even have *edited* my answer since it such an obviously honest mistake.

Comment: @Thomash i deleted my answer but i don't know Why you spoke with me this way!

Comment: @HforHesham Don't get intimidated by such outbursts of primitivism. Just flag the comment as "rude or offensive" and it will get deleted within an hour of two.

Answer (score 2):

It is O(n^2),

```
i = 0;
    j = 1;==>j =array.length.
i = 1;
    j = 1;==>j =array.length.
i = 2;
    j = 2;==>j =array.length.
...
i = n;
    j = n;==>j =array.length.
...
i = array.length;
    j =array.length.
```

So, the loop run **n(n-1)/2** times.It is O(n^2).

and this below is a O(n^2) too :

```
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    for(j = 0; j<n;++j)
    {
        if(...)
           ...
        else
           ...
        ...  
    }
}
```

Comment: See HforHesham's answer and the comments: `i` does not incremented in every iteration.

Comment: @drvdijk Thanks. I am a little sleepy

Comment: @drvdijk what makes you think that Lidong Guo thinks that `i` is incremented in every iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Is's `O(n^2)`. `i` only gets incremented after `j` has run over the full array. This happens for every iteration of the loop, each iteration the input becoming 1 smaller. So `n*(n-1)/2` times, which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Is there a difference between worst case and best case in this algorithm (hint: there isn't)? Then why do you emphasize on the worst case?

Comment: I removed my comment between Thomash' and Marko's comment: indeed, there is no worst-case. It's just `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's `O(n^2)`.

Starting with `i=0`: for j = 1 -> array.length => n interations

Step 2: i = 1 => for j = 2 -> array.length => n - 1 iterations

...

Step n - 1: i = array.length - 2 => for j = array.length - 1 -> array.length => 1 iteration

Therefore, the complexity is `n * (n + 1) / 2`, which is `n^2`.

Answer (score 1):

this is O((n(n+1))/2)

which is O(n^2)

Comment: No, it's O(n^2) but not o(n^2)